# InvalidQueryException despite of correct query

Tags: java, cassandra, resultset

I am using SpringBoot connceted with Hibernate and Cassandra Database. I made couple of methods using ResultSet and everything works perfect till now. I create another method, create query and then ResultSet.

```
String queryString = query.toString().replace("?", dayList.toString());
ResultSet rS = dataSource.executeQuery(queryString);
```

It throws me:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
```

Query is correct. When I execute query in database it returns me proper data.

It is wierd because I use same implementation in previous method and it works.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM object_action_statistics WHERE day IN ('2018-04-29','2018-04-30') AND action_id=14 AND timestamp_from>=1525099500073 AND timestamp_from<1525120897000 ALLOW FILTERING
```

Comment: don't you miss the keyspace here ? 
SELECT * FROM KEYSPACEMISSING.object_action_statistics

Comment: You are right.. I was looking for some bigger trouble and I forgot to add schema name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `ALLOW FILTERING` is big sign that you is on the way to future troubles - you need correct your data model

Comment: As already mentioned you shouldnt be using allow filtering and IN

Comment: @AlexTbk why not use IN and ALLOW FILTERING?

Comment: @Bob https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/  and https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct query should be like this:

`SELECT * FROM KEYSPACE_NAME.object_action_statistics WHERE day IN ('2018-04-29','2018-04-30') AND action_id=14 AND timestamp_from>=1525099500073 AND timestamp_from<1525120897000 ALLOW FILTERING`

I guess you forgot to put keyspace name ahead of table name.